# Animate Slot Machine in python

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyside2

I'm trying to create a slot machine graphic with the numbers 0-9 in each slot, where the numbers scroll to the next one when you hover over them with the mouse and scrollwheel up or down. So far I've got everything working in PySide2 except the animation -- what I've done as an example is simply split the image into individual png files and just tell it to display a new one whereas I'd prefer to use one long picture with all the numbers and just tell the program to scroll the visible section in the direction needed.

Code:

```
class SlotAnimator(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setObjectName('Slot_Frame')
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.hover_over = False
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet.slot_machine_style)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setMaximumSize(400, 200)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.digits = []
        self.readout = [0, 0, 0]
        self.commands = []
        self.pix = [
            QPixmap('./images/0.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/1.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/2.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/3.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/4.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/5.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/6.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/7.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/8.png').scaledToHeight(150),
            QPixmap('./images/9.png').scaledToHeight(150),
        ]
        for each in range(3):
            temp = QLabel()
            temp.setPixmap(QPixmap('./images/slot_digitback.png').scaledToHeight(150))
            self.digits.append(temp)
            self.commands.append(start_scroll(self.digits[-1]))
            self.layout.addWidget(self.digits[-1])
            
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.hover_over = True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.hover_over = False
        else:
            return False
        return True
    
    def wheelEvent(self, wheel_event):
        if self.hover_over:
            if wheel_event.delta() > 0:
                self.readout[2] += 1
                if self.readout[2] == 10:
                    self.readout[1] += 1
                    self.readout[2] = 0
                    if self.readout[1] == 10:
                        self.readout[0] += 1
                        self.readout[1] = 0
                print(self.readout)
            elif wheel_event.delta() < 0:
                if sum(self.readout) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    if self.readout[2] == 0:
                        if self.readout[1] == 0:
                            self.readout[0] -= 1
                            self.readout[1] = 9
                        else:
                            self.readout[1] -= 1
                            self.readout[2] = 9
                    else:
                        self.readout[2] -= 1
            for each in range(len(self.digits)):
                self.digits[each].setPixmap(self.pix[self.readout[each]])
```

How it looks:

[image: Not allowed to embed images yet]

Long 'reel' I hope to use instead:

[image]

Edit: removed a comment line that was just confusing/part of something I tried before. And adding:

```
def start_scroll(the_target):
    scroll = QPropertyAnimation(the_target, b'pos')
    scroll.setDuration(4000)
    scroll.setEndValue(QPoint(0, 200))
    return scroll
```

I think its connected via a qpushbutton currently, and it works though all 3 boxes go to the corner rather than just straight down.

Comment: You mention an "animation", but in your code there's no trace of it. Do you actually want to add an animation feature, or you just directly jump to the desired section of the image? Knowing that difference is very important, as animating such scrolling is much more different than just jumping to the final value, and if you eventually need to do the animation the code will be much more different. Also, right now your code only steps by units, are you expecting it to change tens and hundreds if the mouse is on the respective digit? Have you considered using a basic QSpinBox with custom font?

Comment: Yes I do want animation -- I just wanted to set up the rest of the code to work first. I've tried code with QGraphicsScene and QPropertyAnimation but haven't been able to do more than paste/shrink items with them. I do like your suggestion of a spinbox & custom font, but I'd like to leave my options open especially to learn and grow as a programmer. -- So I'm hoping someone can help me using QGraphicsItem or QPropertyAnimation, if its possible to move objects and mask everything outside a bounding box?

Comment: Well, the fact is that your requirement is much more difficult than you probably think. For instance, what should happen if the user "skips" lots of digits with the mouse wheel, while it's still animating? They would probably expect that the tens digits will switch only when the base unit changes the tens (from 9 to 10 and vice versa). Such kind of display *is* doable, but it's not easy to achieve just by swapping/jumping to elements, especially if you want to show animations at value changes: each digit has to consider its "child" digits.

Comment: Let's suppose that your animation takes 100ms, but I scroll very fast from 89 to 100. A proper widget should switch the tens to 9 when the value changes to 90, and then jump to 0 when the values reach to 100, while the hundreds digit should only jump from 0 to 1 when the value jumps from 99 to 100, and so on. This means that the animation should always take account of its current state and the digits it's "updating", which means that *multiple* animations should probably be used for this, or a slightly advanced computation (based on powers of tens) should be used.

Comment: yep -- I'm currently struggling with that now -- making progress, kinda proud, going to post it if I can figure it out since I can't find one online.

Answer (score 0):

Whoohoo! I finally got it!

Full Code:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import stylesheet


class SlotDigit(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.position = 0
        self.target = 0
        self.step = 0
        self.image_width = 300
        self.gap = self.image_width * 54 / 30
        self.updater = QTimer()
        self.updater.connect(SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.nudge_step)
        self.updater.start(10)
        
        self.back = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap('./images/slot_digitback.png').scaledToHeight(400))
        self.back.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsChildrenToShape)
        self.addToGroup(self.back)
        
        self.image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap('./images/numbers.png').scaledToWidth(self.image_width))
        self.image.setParentItem(self.back)
        self.image.setPos(-20, self.image_width / 10)
        
    def delta_change(self, delta_insert):
        self.target += delta_insert
        
    def nudge_step(self):
        if self.position > 10:
            self.position -= 10
            self.target -= 10
        elif self.position < 0:
            self.position += 10
            self.target += 10
        delta_num = self.target - self.position
        if delta_num != 0:
            if abs(delta_num) < .2:
                self.position = round(self.position)
            else:
                self.position += (delta_num / abs(delta_num)) / 15
            self.image.setPos(self.image.x(), -self.position * self.gap + 30)
        
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.target += int(event.delta() / abs(event.delta()))


def print_this(string):
    print(string)


class SlotMachine(QGraphicsView):
    shout = Signal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet.slate)
        self.setMaximumSize(1800, 900)
        self.items = []
        
        self.scene_1 = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene_1.setSceneRect(QRectF(-40, -40, 1290, 500))
        for each in range(4):
            self.items.append(SlotDigit())
            self.scene_1.addItem(self.items[-1])
            self.items[-1].setPos(300*each, 0)
        self.setScene(self.scene_1)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.shout.connect(print_this)
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            output = []
            for each in range(len(self.items)):
                number = self.items[each].position
                if number == 10:
                    number = 0
                output.append(number)
            integer = "".join([str(int(each)) for each in output])
            self.shout.emit(integer)
        return False


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()

box = SlotMachine(window)
window.setCentralWidget(box)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Stylesheet just says:

```
slate = """
            border-image: url('./images/slot_back-b.png');
"""
```

A fully reusable Slot Machine with animated tumbling. Each digit changes by itself when scrolling with the mouse while hovered over. Clicking on it makes it emit the entire number as a string for some other widgets to use.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately, without both source images it's a bit difficult to test your code, which also has a couple of important problems: first of all, the timer is continuous (so it keeps going on unnecessarily even if there's no change at all); then, there is some problems with the position checking (but I've not been able to fully understand it due to the missing images and the hardcoded sizes); also, that connection style is obsolete, use `self.updater.timeout.connect(self.nudge_step)`; finally, there's no resizing, if scroll bars are shown, the wheel event will scroll the scene;

Comment: Ok, sorry, I appreciate your input, I'll go back and look into it, especially about the timeout signal, which I've never gotten to work.

Comment: I'm curious why PyCharm always registers things qt as qa warnings. I've never gotten the timer timeout to work before because it would flag it no matter what and I kept trying self.updater.connect(timeout(), self.nudget_step)

Comment: Those are just warnings, as far as I know they don't prevent you from running code. The `.connect(SIGNAL, ...)` has been deprecated for years, so you shouldn't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The important premise here is that such a control type is not easy to manage.

There are various aspects that must be considered, most importantly:

- should the "value" of the widget reflect the currently visible value (even while animating), or the target one?
- if we need the signal/slot support, should the signal be emitted when a "target" value has been reached, or when the slot (visible) value changes?
- should we consider the visible value as an integer of the current momentary value, or a rounded one? For instance, if the current visible value is 1.6, should we return 1 or 2?
- should a *value setter* change the actual "target" value, or the shown one?

Considering the above, there are various possible implementations.

### A possible (rather complex, but still effective) solution

In the following example I'm showing how I tried to find a "good" implementation: a *perfect* one is impossible to achieve, but when trying to attempt for a good balance, you've to find "the best of both worlds". I've tried to implement this as close as the general attempt of Qt APIs is.

Some important notes:

- the `value` property will always reflect an `int()` of the visible value: if the shown value is `1.9`, the returned value (and related signal) will still be `1`; this approach is similar to the [mechanical counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_counter) used in old "analog" systems;
- value changes that affect higher digits (for instance, from 9 to 10) will use an animation that only changes the affected digits based on their minimal unit; this is important, because switching from 90 to 200 will not cause a smooth animation of the second digit from 0 to 2, but instantaneous animations that will only occur when the value goes from 99 to 100 and from 199 to 200; considering the above point, and the fact that it's rather difficult to understand the "new value" direction, creating a faithful animation is not only complex, but could also affect performance: for instance, when switching from 918 to 99, how should we animate the tens from 1 to 9 and the unit from 8 to 9?
- the `valueChanged` signal will be emitted in any case, but since it is based on the animation, some values will be skipped: switching from 0 to 100 will result in intermediate signals that will almost always skip values; I added support for a `tracking` property that will update values during animation, but it doesn't update values *linearly*; to my perception, that wouldn't be valid anyway: while I can understand the need for continuous tracking, scrolling from 0 to 1000000 would cause a million signals: do we really need that?
- in order to provide proper image translation, the source pixmap should consider a further margin that corresponds to the spacing between each digit; I took the original image and edited to add a further margin in order to make it compliant to the full image size, but possible vertical margins can be added with the provided `setPixmap()` function arguments;

Considering the above and as already explained, there is no definitive solution: it completely depends on what you need. If you just want an animation that completely disregards the shown value, then you should emit the `valueChanged` only when setting the *target* value. I've provided such feature with the `tracking` property (see above).

Finally:

- this widget is clearly a "fancy" one, a QGraphicsView is probably the best choice, since it could also provide proper scaling. I'll eventually edit this answer with an appropriate implementation.
- to provide proper visual response, I decided to inherit from QAbstractScrollArea with a spin box size hint; the behavior should be similar to a QSpinWidget (including frame animations); this obviously adds some pros and cons: for instance, the widget will always fill the whole layout item width, and changing the size policy will force it to the layout direction; as said above, if you need further control, you need further implementation;

Here is the example. Note that the QProperties (`minimum`, `maximum`, `spacing` and `value`), as with any PyQt widgets, can be added as keywords.
The class creates a default pixmap if no `slot.png` image is provided, based on the default font, but further implementation should be provided for better compatibility.

```
from functools import cached_property
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class SlotWidget(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea):
    _minimum = 0
    _maximum = 999
    _spacing = 4
    _animationDuration = 250
    _visibleValue = _targetValue = 0
    _hoverDigit = -1
    basePixmap = _basePixmap = None
    _wheelUpdatesDigit = True
    _tracking = False

    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        # create a default pixmap (and its related parameters) in case we
        # do not have a proper image for the numbers
        if not self._basePixmap:
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() * 8)
            fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
            digitHeight = fm.ascent()
            _width = 0
            for i in range(10):
                _width = max(_width, fm.horizontalAdvance(str(i)))
            height = fm.height()
            pm = QtGui.QPixmap(_width, height * 10)
            pm.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(pm)
            qp.setFont(font)
            qp.translate(0, -fm.descent())
            r = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, _width, height)
            for i in range(10):
                qp.drawText(r, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(i))
                qp.translate(0, height)
            qp.end()
            SlotWidget._basePixmap = pm
        self._setPixmapData(self._basePixmap, digitHeight)

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_Hover)
        self.setFrameShape(self.StyledPanel|self.Sunken)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        self.setPixmap(self._basePixmap, digitHeight=digitHeight)

    @cached_property
    def animation(self):
        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(self, duration=self._animationDuration)
        animation.valueChanged.connect(self._updateVisibleValue)
        return animation

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def minimum(self):
        return self._minimum

    @minimum.setter
    def minimum(self, minimum):
        self.setRange(int(minimum), self._maximum)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def maximum(self):
        return self._maximum

    @maximum.setter
    def maximum(self, maximum):
        self.setRange(self._minimum, int(maximum))

    def setRange(self, minimum, maximum):
        minimum = max(0, minimum)
        maximum = max(minimum, maximum)
        if self._minimum != minimum or self._maximum != maximum:
            self._minimum = minimum
            self._maximum = maximum
            self._value = self._visibleValue = max(minimum, min(int(self._visibleValue), maximum))
            self.updateGeometry()

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def spacing(self):
        return self._spacing

    @spacing.setter
    def spacing(self, spacing):
        spacing = max(0, spacing)
        if self._spacing != spacing:
            self._spacing = spacing
            self.updateGeometry()

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def value(self):
        return int(self._visibleValue)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        value = max(self._minimum, min(int(value), self._maximum))
        if self.animation.state():
            self.animation.stop()
        self._targetValue = value
        if self._visibleValue != value:
            self._updateVisibleValue(value)

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool)
    def tracking(self):
        return self._tracking

    def setTracking(self, tracking):
        self._tracking = tracking
        self._lastTrackedValue = int(self._visibleValue)

    def _updateVisibleValue(self, value):
        self._visibleValue = value
        if self._tracking and self._lastTrackedValue != int(value):
            self.valueChanged.emit(int(value))
        self._lastTrackedValue = int(value)
        self.viewport().update()

    def scrollToValue(self, value, interval=None):
        if interval == None:
            interval = self._animationDuration
        value = max(self._minimum, min(int(value), self._maximum))
        if self._targetValue == value:
            return
        if not self._tracking:
            self._lastTrackedValue = value
            self.valueChanged.emit(value)
        self._targetValue = value
        if self.animation.state():
            self.animation.stop()
        if self._visibleValue != value:
            self.animation.setDuration(interval)
            self.animation.setStartValue(float(self._visibleValue))
            self.animation.setEndValue(float(value))
            self.animation.start()

    def _setPixmapData(self, pixmap, digitHeight=100, yMargin=0, xMargin=None):
        self._baseWidth = pixmap.width()
        self._fullHeight = pixmap.height()
        self._digitWidth = pixmap.width()
        self._digitHeight = digitHeight
        self._stepHeight = self._fullHeight / 10
        self._fullDigitHeight = int(self._stepHeight)
        if isinstance(xMargin, (int, float)):
            self._leftMargin = self._rightMargin = max(0, int(xMargin))
        else:
            if xMargin is None:
                xMargin = 0, 0
            self._leftMargin = max(0, int(xMargin[0]))
            self._rightMargin = max(0, int(xMargin[1]))
        self._stepDelta = self._stepHeight - self._digitHeight + yMargin

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap, digitHeight=100, yMargin=0, xMargin=None):
        if self.basePixmap != pixmap:
            if not isinstance(pixmap, QtGui.QPixmap) or pixmap.isNull():
                self.basePixmap = self._basePixmap
            else:
                self.basePixmap = pixmap
        self._setPixmapData(pixmap, digitHeight, yMargin, xMargin)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def stepBy(self, delta):
        if not self.animation.state():
            self.scrollToValue(int(self._visibleValue) + delta)
        else:
            add = delta > 0
            dirAdd = self.animation.endValue() > self.animation.startValue()
            if add == dirAdd:
                self.scrollToValue(self._targetValue + delta)
            else:
                self.scrollToValue(int(self._visibleValue) + delta)

    def _digitAt(self, x):
        x -= (self.width() - self._fullWidth) // 2
        halfSpacing = self._spacing / 2
        digitX = self._digitWidth
        for d in self._range:
            if x <= digitX + halfSpacing:
                break
            digitX += self._spacing + self._digitWidth
        return d

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.HoverMove:
            self._hoverDigit = self._digits - self._digitAt(event.pos().x()) - 1
            self.viewport().update()
        elif event.type() == event.HoverLeave:
            self._hoverDigit = -1
            self.viewport().update()
        return super().event(event)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        s = self.sizeHint()
        return int(width * s.height() / s.width())

    def sizeHint(self):
        chars = max(len(str(self._minimum)), len(str(self._maximum)))
        width = self._baseWidth * chars + self._spacing * (chars - 1)
        width += self._leftMargin + self._rightMargin + self.frameWidth() * 2
        return QtCore.QSize(width, self._fullDigitHeight)

    def updateGeometry(self):
        self._digits = len(str(self._maximum))
        self._fullWidth = (
            self._digitWidth * self._digits
            + self._spacing * (self._digits - 1)
        )
        self.setMinimumSize(self._fullWidth, self._stepHeight)
        self._range = range(self._digits)
        self._reverseRange = range(self._digits, -1, -1)
        super().updateGeometry()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        delta = 0
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            delta = 1
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            delta = -1
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageUp:
            if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
                delta = 100
            else:
                delta = 10
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageDown:
            if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
                delta = -100
            else:
                delta = -10
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Home:
            delta = self._maximum
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_End:
            delta = -self._maximum
        if delta:
            self.stepBy(delta)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self._fullWidth, self._stepHeight)
        rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        qp.setClipRect(rect)
        qp.translate(rect.topLeft())

        x = self._fullWidth - self._digitWidth
        limit = self._stepHeight * 9
        rest = self._visibleValue % 1
        height = self._fullDigitHeight - self.frameWidth() * 2
        highlightPen = qp.pen().color()
        highlightPen.setAlphaF(max(.1, highlightPen.alphaF() / 10))
        qp.setPen(highlightPen)
        for digit in self._range:
            value = int(self._visibleValue / 10 ** digit) % 10
            y = self._stepHeight * (value + rest) % self._fullHeight
            if y >= limit:
                qp.drawPixmap(x, self._stepDelta - y + self._fullHeight, self.basePixmap)
            qp.drawPixmap(x, self._stepDelta - y, self.basePixmap)
            if digit == self._hoverDigit:
                qp.drawRoundedRect(x, 0, self._digitWidth - 1, height - 1, 2, 2)
            x -= self._digitWidth + self._spacing
            if value < 9:
                rest = 0

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            delta = 1
        else:
            delta = -1
        if self._wheelUpdatesDigit:
            d = self._digitAt(event.x())
            delta *= 10 ** (self._digits - d - 1)
        self.stepBy(delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(test)
    slot = SlotWidget(minimum=25, maximum=1250)
    slot.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('slot.png'), xMargin=5)
    layout.addWidget(slot)
    spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=slot.minimum, maximum=slot.maximum)
    spin.setKeyboardTracking(False)
    layout.addWidget(spin)

    trackingChk = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Smooth tracking', checked=slot.tracking)
    layout.addWidget(trackingChk)

    def setValueFromSlot(value):
        with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(spin):
            spin.setValue(value)

    slot.valueChanged.connect(setValueFromSlot)
    spin.valueChanged.connect(slot.scrollToValue)
    trackingChk.toggled.connect(slot.setTracking)

    test.show()
    app.exec()
```

As the reader would have probably found already, the above implementation is quite complex. I could have expanded the explanation with all related aspects, but that would have made the whole post even more cumbersome. StackOverflow is not a tutorial website: you have to do the research on your own, and I've already provided more than usually done on a standard post.

I strongly suggest any reader to carefully and patiently **study** the above code and consider all aspects it uses, most importantly:

- [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html), the basic Qt painter handler that allows drawing;
- [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html), responsible of painting basic widgets using the current style, and considering all GUI aspects including those inherited from the OS;
- [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html), which is a fundamental attribute for widgets to allow proper laying out of UI elements in an interface;

As always, the most important sources for learning are documentation and, obviously, *sources*.